# Disabled jQuery UI Button Remains Disabled on Returning to Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, form-submit, double-submit-prevention

I have a [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) submit button on a form when it's clicked to both prevent double-clicking and to also make it visibly clear that it was in fact clicked properly.

So I use jQuery to do this:

```
$('input:submit').click(function() {
    $(this).button('disable');
});
```

It works, but the problem is when the user hits their back button it ***remains disabled***.  What's the proper way to disable a submit button when clicked?  I obviously use jQuery, so preference is to use jQuery.

***UPDATE***: many people suggested I use `$(document).ready(function() {$('input:submit').button('enable');});` to overcome this persistent disabling of the button.  It turns out that won't work if it comes before my button initialization call in `$(function() {}`.  But if I put that button('enable') after my button initialization code, even in the `$(function() {})` section, then it works as expected.

But now I realize this whole button disabling only works in Firefox!  ***If I disable the button, the form won't submit*** in IE and Chrome (haven't tested others)!

***UPDATE 2***: I finally got this to work, though a bit concerned some browsers are not going to be able to submit things with these workarounds...  Here's my final code, would love to hear opinions of potential issues:

```
$(function() {
    $('input:submit').button().click(function() {
        $(this).button('disable');
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
        return false;
    });
    $('input:submit').button('enable');
});
```

Comment: Thank you Hamish for editing my post to reflect my jQuery UI button usage.  I should've been more clear on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input:submit").attr("disabled", "");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:submit').button({ disabled: false});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's staying disabled because the browser does it's best to save form state in history. So I would just recommend attaching to the load event and removing the disabled attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any reference to the `button` method in the jQuery API documentation. Are you using a module of some kind?

Hitting back should reset the form to it's initial state, so I imagine there must be some session magic happening with the `button` method. Try the following instead:

```
$('input:submit').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, forms retain (some of) their state when you click the back button, so you need to enable the submit button when the page is loaded (which will also happen when someone clicks the back button).

Add this to your page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input:submit").button("enable");
});
```

Note that this solution uses the [jQuery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button#method-enable) `button.enable()` method which is the inverse of the `button.disable()` method you used.